# Exiftool in nodejs for heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, exiftool

I have the problem that I need to use the `exiftool`, since I could command more metadata packages that are in NPM. But this program is not loaded in heroku, What is the method to install this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get extra binaries, dependencies, libs, etc onto the dyno, you should specify additional buildpacks as documented here:

- https://github.com/benalavi/buildpack-exiftool

The gist is:

```
heroku buildpack:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi
```

Then in .buildpacks:

```
https://github.com/benalavi/buildpack-exiftool
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
```

That will first download & install exiftool, then install node and use node (the final item listed) as your app buildpack.